# Exception in Contract Reverts Entire Stack, Uses all Gas

Tags: solidity, gas, contract-debugging, abi

I added a check to make sure when I send ether that if it fails, I attempt to abort the transaction using a throw.  Per example here:  [Solidity Exceptions](http://solidity.readthedocs.org/en/latest/control-structures.html?highlight=send#exceptions)

When make a call to a function that does this throw from another contract and the throw fails, all gas is used up on that source contract's gas budget.  (gasUsed == gasSent in the transaction receipt).  This happens no matter how much gas I send.

The throw is inside a complicated loop (business logic), but it's just like the example cited above:

```
// inside complicated business logic I wish to roll back if this fails
if (a.send(remittance) == false) {
    throw;
}
```

The code that is making the call from another contract looks like this.  I'll note there's only one callback currently installed:

```
for(uint i = 0;i < callbacks.length; i++) {
    callbacks[i].oracleCallback(_value, _time, _info);
}
```

I'm using a fairly recent build of the master branch of geth and a fairly recent build (early January) of solidity.

Here's the transaction receipt (private test server):

```
{"transactionHash":"0x61474d8ecd82d5c95d7c9c548f5a4cd5213b16775809580189860bd69773c07a","transactionIndex":0,"blockNumber":440377,"blockHash":"0xb88779e44dabd14fcc55f7a0cdd31aaeab6417b990ed626748d8726463173bad","cumulativeGasUsed":800000,"gasUsed":800000,"contractAddress":null,"logs":[]}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, all EVM exceptions cause all state changes to be rolled back, and all gas is forfeit to the miner. Thus, while throwing errors is convenient,  it sometimes makes sense to just return some error value. You can also use Events to signal an exception occurred.

When calling other contracts, all exceptions bubble up, except when you use the `send` or `call` functions. These are low level functions that send Ether to, or call a method of another contract, but they only return `true` or `false`, if there was an exception.

For example, if you want to call another contract, but protect yourself from exceptions, and limit gas usage, use this:

```
uint gasPerCall = msg.gas / callbacks.length - 200000;
bytes4 abi = bytes4(sha3("oracleCallback(int256,uint256,bytes32)"));

for(uint i = 0; i < callbacks.length; i++) {
    if (callbacks[i].call.gas(gasPerCall)(abi, _value, _time, _info) == false) {
        FailedCallbackEvent(abi, gasPerCall, msg.gas);
    }
}
```

Replace the types in the ABI with the correct types. If the amount of gas sent is not important, you can just use `callbacks[i].call(abi,_value,_time,_info);`

If you want to send Ether along with the call, you can also use `callbacks[i].call.value(1 ether)(abi,_value,_time,_info);`

This will return true if the call succeeded, and false otherwise.

See [the docs](https://solidity.readthedocs.org/en/latest/control-structures.html?highlight=send#exceptions)

Comment: Wow.  That's going to be tough, because sending ether is at the very long end of a chain of business logic involving loops. (e.g. distributing ether to a list of addresses in some proportional or other algorithmic manner).     I'll have to break the loop in two iterations:  Make a list of of all the ether to be sent, then add it all up and make sure there's enough ether.  This makes business logic potentially very complex and thus bug prone.  Please consider fixing (e.g. adding a catch).

Comment: please consider updating the solidity documentation to reflect this.  For contract-contract calls it's very problematic.    Please provide a link to the rationale

Comment: btw I had this throw occur when I called the contract from web3 and I didn't get an exception thrown in my javascript code (I throw when gasUsed == gasSent).  So is there a behavior difference between contract-contract and outside world-contract?

Comment: Okay, sorry to scare you. I hadn't noticed that you were talking about a contract-contract call issue. I updated with a fix.

Comment: When calling from web3, there's no actual transaction occurring, so it doesn't quite follow all of the EVM rules, like Out of Gas exceptions.

Comment: I tried that, though I don't know why you need to create the ABI to do that.  Still consumes all the gas:

`uint gasPerCall = msg.gas / callbacks.length - 200000;

        for(uint i = 0;i < callbacks.length; i++) {
            callbacks[i].oracleCallback.gas(gasPerCall)(_value, _time, _info);
        }
`

Comment: Yes, because using the method itself isn't exception-safe. You need to use the `call` function, which is a low-level function that does not throw an exception on failure. The `call` function issues a raw call, so you need to put the function signature as the first argument, which is how normal function calls work at the low level

Comment: thanks.  this is a fairly subtle but potentially fatal nuance that the normal call behavior doesn't act like the low level call behavior in solidity...

Comment: I think the idea is that, like in most languages, if a call fails, all calls relying on it should fail as well, to prevent unanticipated consequences.

Comment: yes but when you fan out to other other calls that's why you have a catch.  Also in other languages you don't expect all your gas to be used up!.   BTW the call isn't actually happening.  How to debug..
is the ABI above correct for this?

`function oracleCallback(int _value, uint _time, bytes32 info) external;`

Comment: No, the ABI is `oracleCallback(int,uint,bytes32)` . I was assuming `_value` was a uint.

Comment: Yes, I fixed the int part, I'll keep debugging until the callback happens.  BTW "like other languages" seems like an oddity to me.  I think of these calls as more like a unix process-process call.  Thrown exceptions in one process don't affect the other process...

Comment: I see it as a function call stack. The language is still evolving rapidly, try/catch will probably be coming soon.

Comment: BTW I'm using object inheritance to get that ABI correct at compile time (abstract base class defines oracleCallback().  Is there name mangling that's messing up the creation of the ABI?

Comment: That shouldn't matter. We should move this conversation to [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34620/ethereum) though.

Comment: apparently stackexchange prefers comment spam to chat, I don't have enough credits to chat.  try gitter...

Comment: okay, [solidity](https://gitter.im/ethereum/solidity) room it is.

Comment: Just to be clear, you CANNOT use the aliased types in the ABI hash, you must be explicit.  i.e. this won't work, you'll get the wrong value `sha3("oracleCallback(int,uint,bytes32)")`.   I'll also note that you should add a debug event to a contract's default function that logs at least the ABI so you can debug when you make an error... e.g. `DefaultFuncEvent(msg.sender, msg.sig, msg.gas, msg.value, msg.data);`